# How to improve NSXMLParser performance

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application where I use `NSXMLParser` to parse an XML file. At the moment this takes 8 seconds. But my requirement is to do the parsing within 5 seconds. How can I improve the performance of my parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

1. use a faster phone
2. Use a smaller XML
3. Use a faster parser:
   [Benchmarks on XML processors](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

I would say from a simple reading TBXML seems worth checking out